# How can I fix the "The specified database connection is not defined: default" error?

Tags: drush

I installed PHP 7.4.21, then Drupal 9.2.1, and Drush 10.5.0 with Composer as well.

Running Drush without arguments, I get the list of all the available commands.
Running `drush cr` gives me the following error.

> The specified database connection is not defined: default

`drush cr --root=/home/ip/d916/web` gives the same error.

The output of `drush cr -vvv` is the following.

> #### Exception trace
>
> at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:371
> Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:169
> Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:258
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:176
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:437
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:240
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:176
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/ChainedFastBackendFactory.php:89
> Drupal\Core\Cache\ChainedFastBackendFactory->get() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheFactory.php:83
> Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheFactory->get() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:258
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:176
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:437
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:240
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:176
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:586
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->preHandle() at /home/ip/d916/web/core/includes/utility.inc:35
> drupal_rebuild() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/CacheCommands.php:234
> Drush\Commands\core\CacheCommands->rebuild() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:257
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:212
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:176
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:311
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1027
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:48
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
> require() at /home/ip/d916/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4

Composer works without any mistake. Drupal work fine too. Unfortunately I can't work without Drush 10.

How can I fix the *The specified database connection is not defined: default* error?

Comment: Can you share database details from your settings.php. It seems you haven't configured it properly

Comment: Please share the output of `drush status`.

Comment: As side note: The previous comments are asking to give that information in the question, not in answers. Answers aren't used to give more information to answer the question. Stack Exchange sites aren't forums, but Q&A sites: A user asks a question that other users answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that Drupal works fine. Do you really mean that your Drupal 9.2.1 website is fully functional without a database connection? That is surprising!

You can start by connecting to this environment via `ssh` and testing a connection to the database using the command-line `mysql` utility and the database authentication credentials stored in your `settings.php` file.

If you get a successful connection, run some diagnostic commands like `` USE `drupal`; `` (replacing `drupal` with the DB name specified in your settings) and `SHOW TABLES;` and `` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `node`; `` (just be very careful not to issue any commands that insert, update, or delete any data!)

If Drupal really can connect to the database, and you can connect in this way from the command line, then you will have narrowed the problem down to Drush.

You can make sure that you are really running the correct project-local version of Drush 10 that you installed with Composer by executing `which drush` at the command prompt to see if you are instead using a gloabally installed Drush, perhaps even a different version.

If that is the case, please specify the full path to your local Drush to be sure you are executing the correct Drush PHAR:

```
$ cd /home/ip/d916/
$ ./vendor/bin/drush status
$ ./vendor/bin/drush cr
```

If these commands work for you, then you have different options depending on your hosting. The [Drush docs](https://www.drush.org/latest/) are excellent, and will help you to decide the correct path forward.

Comment: It could also be that Drush is executed from the wrong directory and it doesn't find the settings.php file, or it finds a settings.php file that doesn't contain the database connection information, or the correct database connection information. This would explain why the Drupal site works but Drush reports an error.

Comment: Drush was the problem. The downloaded 10.5.0 called by an alias didn't work for me. After runnning `composer require drush/drush`  and `echo export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` I had the correct version and both Drush and Drupal work fine.

Comment: I want to add my experience today to this question/answer. I had the 
exact same problem as listed in the question, though the op's final answer didn't solve it for me. The steps inside this upvoted answer DID help. I could see that no matter what I did, I could not get a connection to the DB. None of my colleagues had the error I had. I ended up chucking the entire repo and reinstalling it. Same code, same steps, same files, no manual changes, but this time the DB connection formed. Drush commands worked and the site came up first try. Go figure. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an extra file with your local settings, like for example  `settings.local.php`, check if it is placed in the correct directory.

In this case it must be in the `sites/default/` directory, not in the `sites/` root folder. Most likely the error is caused by a misplaced configuration file.

If that's not the case, or you have only one `settings.php`, check if you have a valid configuration for your database in the `$databases[][]` array in it, for the "default" site it must be named "`$databases['default']['default']`" and must contain all your database information.

Example:

```php
## database settings
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => 'drupal9',
  'username' => 'drupal9',
  'password' => 'drupal9',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'database',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently. If this is a shared host, or a multisite setup, you will need to include the `--uri=https://[example-domain.com]` parameter with your drush command. That's how it is going to find your particular site's db connection info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using local development, such as with Vagrant, Lando, or DDEV, be sure you've established a shell connection to your environment using a command such as `vagrant ssh`, `lando ssh`, or `ddev ssh`, then run your commands from within your SSH session. Otherwise, the Drupal Console command can't connect to the database.

This is true for any other commands like `drush` that require database access, although many local development environments have shortcuts like `ddev drush` that handle that connection for you. Drupal console does not have such a shortcut, so an SSH connection to your local environment is essential.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue while executing a drush command. The reason behind my error was a missing directory alias in sites.php file. For ex: I had a site with "example.local.com" and I had created a site folder with the name "example". I had to add a directory alias in sites.php file to fix the issue.

```
$sites['example.local.com'] = 'example';
```

Hope this helps someone!!

Refer: https://www.techpond.in/drush-specified-database-connection-not-defined-default