drush updatedb fails to complete: Bootstrap fails at phase 5, can't find Drush config file
Trying to use drush updatedb after running core updates. Updatedb fails. Code snippet below.
EDIT:
Project: Website built by 3rd party firm and handed over to my department after the contract to perform ongoing updates/bug fixes/security/etc.
Environment: Website is hosted on Pantheon. Codebase is saved on Bitbucket. I am using an SSH clone from Pantheon, not Bitbucket (which is locked) on WSL w/ Ubuntu. Instance of WSL has composer, ddev, drush, and drupal installed; as well as git and terminus. I am open to feedback if I should be cloning it differently.
A slack channel suggested the solution is revealed in the penultimate line about not finding a database. Said I need to get a copy of it from Pantheon, but I do not know how to do that. Can someone please help? Any info is helpful and appreciated. Many Thanks. Here is the code:
mjx@mjovanov:~/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023$ vendor/bin/drush updatedb -vvv
 [preflight] Config paths: /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/web/drush/sites,/home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/src
 [info] Starting bootstrap to full [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase 5 [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Change working directory to /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/web [0.77 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Initialized Drupal 10.3.0 root directory at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/web [0.77 sec, 9.93 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.77 sec, 9.93 MB]
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.78 sec, 10.37 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.78 sec, 10.37 MB]
 [debug] Could not find a Drush config file at sites/default/drush.yml. [0.78 sec, 10.62 MB]
 [info] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.78 sec, 10.62 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.78 sec, 10.62 MB]
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.78 sec, 10.62 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.78 sec, 10.62 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.79 sec, 10.93 MB]
 [info] Unable to connect to database with message: The specified database connection is not defined: default. More debug information is available by running `drush status`. This may occur when Drush is trying to bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details. [0.79 sec, 10.94 MB]
 [info] Could not bootstrap at phase 5 [0.79 sec, 10.93 MB]

In BootstrapHook.php line 40:

  [Exception]
  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.


Exception trace:
  at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:40
 Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:44
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->doInitializeHook() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:36
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:29
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:145
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:376
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:292
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1096
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:324
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:175
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:110
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:40
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:139
 require() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
 include() at /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/bin/drush:119

mjx@mjovanov:~/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023$ vendor/bin/drush status
Drupal version : 10.3.0
Site URI       : http://default
PHP binary     : /usr/bin/php8.1
PHP config     : /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
PHP OS         : Linux
PHP version    : 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18
Drush script   : /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/bin/drush
Drush version  : 12.5.2.0
Drush temp     : /tmp
Drush configs  : /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
Drupal root    : /home/mjx/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023/web
Site path      : sites/default
mjx@mjovanov:~/websites/arch/cmu-soa-2023$ vendor/bin/drush topic docs-aliases

In TopicCommands.php line 73:

  docs-aliases topic not found.


Do either of these answer your question? They refer to the same issue. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/304145/how-can-i-fix-the-the-specified-database-connection-is-not-defined-default-er, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459063/the-specified-database-connection-is-not-defined-default-for-drupal-drush

Thank you for the help. I don't believe this resolved the issue.

You will have to update the Question to indicate all the things you tried and your overall setup, or it will be closed as needing more information. It is not essentially different from those other questions in its current form.

Where is the database for this website running at this time? If it is on Pantheon, it would be very unusual indeed, even dangerous, for you to run drush updatedb remotely, from a different codebase. Are you familiar with the common workflows for working with sites hosted on Pantheon?

I suppose I understand in theory that a database exists separate from the codebase (?), but I don't know where this database would be, if it is not bitbucket or pantheon.

I saw this: https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer#s-run-database-updates
"we included the Drush commands necessary to complete an update, many people find Drush quicker and easier than the web-based admin area.
If I commit/push just the drupal/core updates w/o updating the database, it appears in Pantheon's dev environment to be merged, with a checkbox that says "Run update.php after merging?". So per the quotation above, does that checkbox essentially function the same as trying to use drush updatedb? So can I skip this step in drush entirely?

Humbly, no; I am not familiar with the common workflows. Apologies for that. I have done LinkedIn Learning Essential Training courses on Drupal, Git; and am now starting BitBucket and Pipelines. I have been trying to run updates in WSL with a pantheon SSH clone, but now I'm guessing I shouldn't have to SSH at all, and that I should be able to somehow run composer in a terminal window within BitBucket, just don't know how yet.

So the answer to this question is "you did not load a copy of the site'

You did not load a copy of the site's database into DDEV with ddev import-db and are not prefixing Drush commands with ddev exec, as in ddev exec drush udpatedb.

It's just ddev drush nowadays without exec. Maybe OP can also ddev drush sql-sync @dev @self or ddev drush si --existing config.
